# Avoid method calls or property accesses on a "dynamic" target

Tags: flutter, dart

In this example below which unmaps the json from Firebase.
Everywhere where I get data as `Map<String, dynamic>` - like `orderId` - its ok.
But everywhere where I have map inside another map - like `address` - it gives me a warning

> "Avoid method calls or property accesses on a "dynamic" target."

Its not critical but I found on google that it provokes productivity penalties.
Can someone share why it is so and how to avoid it

```
Order.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    orderId = data['orderId'] as int;
    address = data['location']['address'].toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I think it is worth noting that the mentioned size and runtime penalties are generally not a concern, they are likely to be unnoticable.

the best fix you have for this is simply to explicitly cast your value:

```
address = (data['location'] as Map<String, dynamic>)['address'].toString();
```

I am not sure if the above will be enough or if you will have to also cast `address`:

```
address = ((data['location'] as Map<String, dynamic>)['address'] as Object).toString()
```

The performance/size issue comes from the time it takes the application to figure out if `data['location']` is a map. by adding `as`, you are telling it to not check and to not worry.

Comment: yeah, it removed the warning. thanks a lot

Comment: Any idea how to cast the following having the same issue with 'val'  .set(training.toJson((val) => val.toJson().toString()));